# Storing Date and Time in SQLite Android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, date

I am creating an android application and I need to store date and time values from the user to my sqlite database. I am using date and time picker tools available in eclipse.
Can anyone please tell me how to store these values in sqlite database(which format)..??
Any help is be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Sqlite documentation on Data types: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html . Also, http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have "real" data types in SQLite. There are only 5 of them and they serve as a hint, not a restriction. So you can put anything there, e.g. String in an Integer field.

Read more Here: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html especially this "1.2 Date and Time Datatype", it addresses your specific concern.

Comment: but how do i get these values from the date and time picker..??

Comment: Well, it's not really a kind of question you can ask on SO. It's a community which may help you if you encounter a problem, but won't write the code for you. To help you start - this is a nice tutorial on how to use a DatePicker http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html. And here you can find the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html. When you instantiate your DatePicker widget you should just call `getYear()` or any other of its methods to retrieve the date put by user